# How to get objects from div with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm not very familliar with BeautifulSoup.
I have the html code like (it's only part of it):

```html
<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
<a class="link-box" href="//en.wikibooks.org/">
<strong>English</strong><br>
<em>Open-content textbooks</em><br>
<small>51 000+ pages</small></a>
</div>
```

On the output I should get (and for other languages):

```
English: 51 000+ pages.
```

I tried something like:

```
for item in soup.find_all('div'):
    print item.get('class')
```

But this does not work. Can you help me, or at least lead to solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`item.get()` returns *attribute values*, not text contained under an element.

You can get the text directly contained in elements with the [`Element.string` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), or all contained text (recursively) with the [`Element.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

Here, I'd search for div elements with a `lang` attribute, then use the contained elements to find strings:

```
for item in soup.find_all('div', lang=True):
    if not (item.strong and item.small):
        continue
    language = item.strong.string
    pages = item.small.string
    print '{}: {}'.format(language, pages)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
... <a class="link-box" href="//en.wikibooks.org/">
... <strong>English</strong><br>
... <em>Open-content textbooks</em><br>
... <small>51 000+ pages</small></a>
... </div>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> for item in soup.find_all('div', lang=True):
...     if not (item.strong and item.small):
...         continue
...     language = item.strong.string
...     pages = item.small.string
...     print '{}: {}'.format(language, pages)
... 
English: 51 000+ pages
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this code throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'` in both language and pages

Comment: @szkodnik: then you have `<div lang="..">` elements *elsewhere* in your HTML that do not have a `<strong>` or `<small>` child element. You could guard against that; I'll update.